# str_replace exact match only

Tags: php, string, str-replace

Good Day,

I am trying to create a morse code to text and text to morse code converter.

My code:

```
$letter = str_split(strtolower($_POST['text']));
$morse = $_POST['morse'];
$morsecmp = explode(" ",$morse);
$letter = implode(" ",$letter);
$mode = $_POST['sub'];

$morsecode = array(".-","-...","-.-.","-..","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",
            ".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-.","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".");
$letters = array("a","b","c","d","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
            "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","e");

if($mode == "Text to Morse Code"){  
    $letter = str_replace($letters,$morsecode,$letter);
    $translated = $letter;
}else{
    for($x=0;$x<sizeof($letters);$x++){
        for($y=0;$y<sizeof($morsecmp);$y++){

            if($morsecode[$x] === $morsecmp[$y]){
                echo $morsecode[$x]." === ".$letters[$x]."<br>";
                $morse = str_replace($morsecode[$x],$letters[$x],$morse);
            }
        }
    }
    $translated = $morse;
}
```

sample input:

> .... . .-.. .-.. ---   .-- --- .-. .-.. -..

sample output:

> h e ed ed o   w o r ed d

expected output:

> hello wolrd

My problem is that when converting from morse code to text some characters are not captured properly due to str_replace limit where it will replace all string that is similar to the needle, so if i have to replace all "." to e it will also change "...." which should be actually an h.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just when you repalce the characters add an extra space for the `search` string.

```
 $morse = $_POST['morse']." ";  // this is to add an extra space at the end of the morse string.
```

Now we replace all occurrences of morse code strings followed by space with the desired letter.

```
 $morse = str_replace($morsecode[$x]." ",$letters[$x],$morse);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't have the full alphabet stored in your array. I noticed you're missing 'e'.

Blow the morse code into an array with `explode(' ', $morse_code)` and then do a replace on the array (use '/' to delimit words).

Condense it back to a string with `implode()`.

heres an array for you to use, its got the whole alphabet (you can use `array_flip` to switch the keys and values for translating back and forth)

```
$translator_table = array(
'A' => '.-',
'B' => '-...',
'C' => '-.-.',
'D' => '-..',
'E' => '.',
'F' => '..-.',
'G' => '--.',
'H' => '....',
'I' => '..',
'J' => '.---',
'K' => '-.-',
'L' => '.-..',
'M' => '--',
'N' => '-.',
'O' => '---',
'P' => '.--.',
'Q' => '--.-',
'R' => '.-.',
'S' => '...',
'T' => '-',
'U' => '..-',
'V' => '...-',
'W' => '.--',
'X' => '-..-',
'Y' => '-.--',
'Z' => '--.',
'0' => '-----',
'1' => '.----',
'2' => '..---',
'3' => '...--',
'4' => '....-',
'5' => '.....',
'6' => '-....',
'7' => '--...',
'8' => '---..',
'9' => '----.',
'.' => '.-.-.-',
',' => '--..--',
'?' => '..--.',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to replace exact matches is:

```
   $morse = preg_replace("#{$morsecode[$x]}#", $letters[$x], $morse, 1); //Limit to 1
```